# logic behind recursive function for checking palindrome words

Tags: python, recursion, palindrome

I have the below code in Python to check whether or not a string is a palindrome:

```
def palin_rec(text):
    text=text.lower()
    if len(text)==1 or len(text)==0:
        return True
    else:
        if text[0]==text[-1] and palin_rec(text[1:-1]):
            print(palin_rec(text[1:-1]))
            return True
        else:               
            return False

palin_rec("rotator")
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
Out[12]: True
```

Can anyone explain the working of the piece of recursive call `palin_rec(text[1:-1])`? I added the `print(palin_rec(text[1:-1]))` function to understand how it works, and it printed out 7 Boolean output (`True`). For the example string "`rotator`", if slicing `[1:-1]`, it represents "`otato`", so how come it output 7 booleans when I printed the recursion out?
Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: To be clear, the confusion is about how many times the recursive call happens? Or what exactly are you asking? What exactly did you think should happen instead, and why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. I'm guessing it has something to do with the contents of `is_palindrome`, which you haven't shown. I assume you're leaning on an existing, non-recursive implementation in order to verify that this one is doing the right thing?

Comment: Yes, I am confused how many times the recursive call happens. I have no idea about what should happen instead of boolean outcome, that's why I ask why it outputs 7 times of boolean outcome

Comment: If you don't understand how recursion works *in general*, then you should a) first try to search for an explanation that works for you; b) in particular check previous Stack Overflow questions to see if one is close enough for you; c) clearly explain the problem, if none of those work.

Comment: I edited my question, is_palindrome is wrong, it should not be there, it should be print(palin_rec(text[1:-1]))

Comment: I searched and still confused

Comment: Okay, so. You understand, then, that you will be making the recursive call *twice* each time? Once in `if text[0]==text[-1] and palin_rec(text[1:-1]):` and the other in `print(palin_rec(text[1:-1]))`? The result from the first time will *not* be used for the `print` call; it will try again. However, I don't understand why you're `print`ing here, because you're inside an `if` block, you therefore *know* that `True` was returned.

Comment: Really? You put `how does recursion work` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+does+recursion+work), and not only are you "still confused", but you can't come up with **anything** to say about your confusion, other than that you are "still confused"?

Comment: Perhaps it would help intuition to add "text" to the print statement.

Comment: @MarkLavin Oh it is good idea, yes, what I want is to get some intuition how recursive call works for this string